# PLSQL : FORALL insert when data is NOT from the type

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, bulkinsert, forall

I want to use `FORALL` to insert data into a table. But, in my below code I will not be able to 
get `l_final_amt` and `l_reference_number` variables outside the `FOR` loop of `l_tbl_table_test_retrieve`.

How to use `FORALL` to insert data into a table when values are not in the given type?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_FORALL AS
PROCEDURE pr_test_FORALL;
END test_FORALL;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_FORALL AS
PROCEDURE pr_test_FORALL IS

TYPE ty_tbl_table_test IS TABLE OF table_test%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
l_tbl_table_test_retrieve            ty_tbl_table_test;
l_tbl_table_test                     ty_tbl_table_test;
l_final_amt                          INTEGER;
l_reference_number                   VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
          SELECT * BULK COLLECT
          INTO   l_tbl_table_test_retrieve
          FROM   table_test t1;

          FOR i IN 1 .. l_tbl_table_test_retrieve.COUNT
          LOOP

          l_tbl_table_test(l_tbl_table_test.COUNT + 1) := l_tbl_table_test_retrieve(i);
          l_final_amt := l_final_amt + 10;
          l_reference_number := SYSDATE + l_tbl_table_test_retrieve(i).ID;

          insert into some_other_table(fname, address,final_amt,ref_number)
          values(l_tbl_table_test_retrieve(i).fname, l_tbl_table_test_retrieve(i).address,l_final_amt,l_reference_number); 

          END LOOP;

        --I want to insert into some_other_table using FORALL. But,l_final_amt and l_reference_number variables
          -- are not available in l_tbl_table_test_retrieve.    

EXCEPTION
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('EXCEPTION occurred');

END;

END pr_test_FORALL;
END test_FORALL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cursor and add the fields into the rows returned by the cursor:

```
PROCEDURE pr_test_FORALL IS
  DECLARE csrData AS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT t1.*,
           NULL AS COUNT_VAL,
           NULL AS FINAL_AMT,
           NULL AS REFERENCE_NUMBER
      FROM TABLE_TEST t1;

  TYPE ty_tbl_table_test IS
    TABLE OF csrData%ROWTYPE  -- Note: csrData%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  l_tbl               ty_tbl_table_test;
  l_final_amt         INTEGER := 0;
  l_reference_number  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  OPEN csrData

  FETCH csrData
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tbl;

  CLOSE csrData;

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_tbl.COUNT LOOP
    l_final_amt := l_final_amt + 10;
    l_tbl(i).FINAL_AMT := l_final_amt;
    l_tbl(i).REFERENCE_NUMBER := SYSDATE + l_tbl(i).ID;
  END LOOP;

  FORALL i IN l_tbl.FIRST..l_tbl.LAST
    INSERT INTO SOME_OTHER_TABLE
      (FNAME, ADDRESS, FINAL_AMT, REF_NUMBER)
    VALUES
      (l_tbl(i).FNAME,
       l_tbl(i).ADDRESS,
       l_tbl(i).FINAL_AMT,
       l_tbl(i).REFERENCE_NUMBER);
EXCEPTION
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('EXCEPTION occurred');
END pr_test_FORALL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the whole thing into two inserts of the below form into the required tables.

I see that in your code `l_reference_number` is defined as a `VARCHAR2` variable but it sounds like a number. ( `SYSDATE + some_number` ) will yield a date type. It will be implicitly converted into a string based on your `NLS_` settings when you assign it to a varchar2. I'm not sure what do you want to store in there as a "`REFERENCE_NUMBER`".

```
 INSERT INTO some_other_table (
      fname,
      address,
      final_amt,
      ref_number
 )
      SELECT fname,
             address,
             10 * ROWNUM  AS final_amt,
             SYSDATE + id  as reference_number 
      FROM table_test;
```